# Is it possible to predict age in an ROC analysis

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to determine if mean and median values for my subjects can be predicted by their age. Is it possible to do this sort of analysis with ROC analysis to obtain sensitivity and specificity?

```
age     minvalue    meanvalue
11      45.1279     740.9683
13      42.3652     100.1476
9       71.5        91.0788
10      44.09       68.82
```

Comment: It isn't really clear what you have in mind here. That may be because the answer is *no*, but it may be genuinely unclear. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your goals? Can you post a small example dataset? For starters, "mean and median values" of *what*?

Comment: @gung I have mean and median values of test scores and the goal is to determine if their age influences their test scores.

Comment: ROC curves should play no role in this type of question.

Comment: @FrankHarrell is this because I am trying to use a continuous variable to predict

Comment: No.  ROC curves are used (sometimes) to assess the performance of a continuous variable or more often of a whole model.  But not to develop the model.  And sens and spec have major problems - see [here](http://fharrell.com/post/class-damage).

Comment: @FrankHarrell Interesting. Would a classification model better suit my needs?

Comment: No, that's the last thing you need.  See [this](http://fharrell.com/post/classification).  But I don't understand your ultimate goal.